# Social sharing and head tags of a specific page in a React app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a React App, made with CRA. One specific page of the app, let's say its a post, needs to be sharable in social media, so I need to insert tags on the head of the page. As React generates the DOM elements with JS I can't just put it as jsx.

I think I need some kind of server side rendering for this, I would like to know if it's possible to make just this page SSR without having to eject CRA and migrate all the app to something like Next.js.

What would be the best decision here? Can someone point me to some direction?

Thanks in advance, have a good day people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were having the same problem and migrated the app to nextJS where you can have the existing components to include into pages by importing them where the content becomes SSR.

Always prefer the URL slug to be dynamic //example.com/apple-iphone-12 for which u can use dynamic page name using NextJS Dynamic Pages pages/[post].js and routing.

You can inject OpenGraph content using Next/Head which allows to add meta content.

Then use **react-share** which is a simplified form where url of current page and image is enough (additional content can be added if required).

This will give the ability for site to be get crawled by google effectively and also will help for further enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst SSR is one possible solution, it may be just as suitable and easier for you to use something such as [react-helmut](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) - a library that allows you to add HTML tags to pages.

```
import React from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Helmet>
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="My site" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="Description of my site." />
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/image.png" />
      </Helmet>
      <div>{/* app content... */}</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Because later tags overwrite duplicate changes, you can set one set of tags for your entire site, then in each post's Component have a set of tags wrapped in `<Helmet>` that are specific to that post.

One point to note using this technique vs SSR is that the consumer of the meta tags needs to be able to parse and render the JS. This isn't such a problem these days, but may not apply to all cases.